# How can i get the hours from 9,633333333333333E+38 using C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, timespan

I need to convert the value `9,633333333333333E+38` (which is a double) to hours.

I've already tried to use the `Timespan.FromHours()` method but it actually sees the value as `96333333333333333333333333333333333333333.38` ending up with the error: "Timespan overflowed because the duration is too long".

Comment: What unit is your value currently in?

Comment: So...you're attempting to convert that number of hours to hours? Please rephrase your question with specifics and what your initial value represents.

Comment: Looks like you are getting an overflow error from dividing by zero or something similar.

Comment: Bernardo, what is this number? This is really intriguing.

Answer (score 5):

A TimeSpan has a maximum value, as seen by the `MaxValue` field.

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
// 10675199.02:48:05.4775807
```

10675199 days is [about](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10675199+days+to+hours) 2.562×10^8 hours. That's smaller than your 9x10^38 hours you're trying to input.

9,633333333333333E+38 hours is [about](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=9.633333333333333E%2B38+hours) 8000000000000000000000000 times the current life of the universe. Not exactly something TimeSpan was designed for.

TimeSpan doesn't look to be the tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great answer- I was thinking about providing a method that splits his huge double-hours into a `TimeSpan[]` where each contains `TimeSpan.MaxValue` apart from the last one which contains the remanining. I should have better looked earlier at your answer, then i'd have noticed that it's a waste of time since i will get an `OutOfMemoryException` :)

Comment: Thanks guys, this morning we detected that the error was in the data conversion within the database, sorry for the trouble and thanks for the answers.